Are Zombees possible?
Suppose that a necromancer has the corpses of a large number of bees (a whole swarm of them, in fact) that have been killed in such a way that it leaves the individual bee corpses intact.
Is it possible for a necromancer to use Animate Dead to animate these dead bees as zombies... Zombees?  If it is possible, would this now undead swarm of bees still be a swarm, save that now the swarm has undead traits, or would it be necessary to animate individual bees?

I like your question and I appreciated even more as Tony Todd, the actor from Candyman, sadly has passed away. x

@Senmurv I never saw Candyman.

@Monty Wild so this is a coincidence? Unbeelievable! (P.s.: RIP Tony Todd)

Maybee, ask your DM
Animate Dead says:

This spell turns the bones or bodies of dead creatures into undead skeletons or zombies that follow your spoken commands. (…) A zombie can be created only from a mostly intact corpse. The corpse must be that of a creature with a true anatomy.

So far so good. But what is a "true anatomy". If we look it up under the Zombie template, it says:

"Zombie" is an acquired template that can be added to any corporeal creature (other than an undead) that has a skeletal system (referred to hereafter as the base creature).

While bees do not have bones, they have an exoskeleton made from chitine, so they do have a skeletal system. And they are corporeal, so they qualify.
The major difficulty will be deploying the material component:

You must place a black onyx gem worth at least 25 gp per Hit Die of the undead into the mouth or eye socket of each corpse you intend to animate. The magic of the spell turns these gems into worthless, burned-out shells.

For a Giant Bee, this should be possible. So you can have Giant Zombees. But what about normal Bees?
There are no stats in the game for an individual, normal bee. Only for a honey bee swarm. A swarm technically also counts as a creature

For game purposes a swarm is defined as a single creature with a space of 10 feet—gigantic hordes are actually composed of dozens of swarms in close proximity. A swarm has a single pool of Hit Dice and hit points, a single initiative modifier, a single speed, and a single Armor Class

And a swarm of Fine creatures consists of 10,000 creatures1. So what does this mean for placing the material components on "the mouth or eye socket of each corpse"? Does a dead swarm still count as a single creature's corpse? The swarm rules do not address this directly. If so and if you somehow manage to place an onyx on a bee's eye socket, you are good to go on your Honey Zombee Swarm. If you would have to do so for each individual bee‘s corpse, you‘d need a lot of castings and 250,000 gp worth of onyx to pull it off. I think it is more likely in the spirit of the rules to treat it as a single creature, but on the other hand, it is probably not what Animate Dead meant with "a creature with a true anatomy". The swarm does not have one anatomy. So I think, wether to allow this for swarms is a DM call.

1
See the rules for swarms.

I rather thought that the 'true anatomy' thing was to disqualify oozes, puddings, gelatinous cubes and the like.

I was thinking on those lines, too. That "true anatomy" means it has organs. I don't think that the swarm quality comes after the bees have been zombified. Also, where in the description does it say a swarm is 10,000 creatures. I couldn't find that. Please reference that. ...but yeah I love the idea of Zombees despite the cost.

@Senmurv It‘s in the swarm rules, I added a reference

PS I also love the idea of zombees. I as a DM would probably allow it at least once, and see how unbalancing the undead swarm would be — they‘re kinda hard to kill, after all.

Hmm, grind up the black onyx gem and sprinkle it on flowers that the bees visit. Then lightly kill them when they already have the gem dust in their mouth.

+1 for the answer, I'd give +2 for Maybee if I could

@candied_orange you make the swarm in the shape of a face and place the black onyx in the face's eye...
or more rule based: Glyph of Warding? Material Component:
You trace the glyph with incense, which must first be sprinkled with powdered diamond worth at least 200 gp.
still $$$ but way less than 250k gp.

i'd probably consider whether the corpses came from multiple "hives". make the necro roll a check to search for queens, animating each queen animates that queen's "hive" as a swarm creature. in practice: maybe the corpses represent 3-5 hives and the necro manages to find and animate two or three queens.

I’ve already upvoted, but a couple of minor points: it is an assumption to say that the “true anatomy” rule corresponds to the requirements of the templates—it is entirely possible for the spell to introduce additional requirements that the templates don’t have, which “true anatomy” might or might not be doing. Moreover, even if a bee has a true anatomy, it may well be an open question with a swarm of bees treated as a singular creature does—it arguably has multiple separate anatomies without any “true anatomy” covering the entire creature.

Spells other than animate dead may be relevant, too
Nobody the Hobgoblin’s fine answer covers animate dead well—it’s not definitive (does a swarm have “a true anatomy”? does “each corpse” count the swarm as one creature, or 10,000?), but that’s the rules’ fault, the spell simply isn’t definitive. I have nothing to add there.
But there are other spells that produce undead minions, and may be different from animate dead. Not as many as expected, but nonetheless:
Animate legion (clr 4, sor/wiz 5; Heroes of Battle)
Animate legion creates as many skeletons or zombies as you can fit within a 15-foot radius with total HD no greater than twice your caster level. It requires a single 100-gp black onyx, rather than requiring one per corpse, so you don’t have to worry about putting 10,000 onyxes in the eyes of 10,000 bee corpses, which may or may not be required by animate dead.
It also says

See animate dead, page 199 of the Player’s Handbook, for information on what is required to create a skeleton or zombie from a corpse.

So animate legion pretty much has the same “true anatomy” issue that animate dead does.
Also, animate legion does not inherently give you any control over the created undead, so you’ll want rebuke undead or control undead for that.
Plague of undead (clr 9, sor/wiz 9; Spell Compendium)
This 9th-level necromancy from Spell Compendium works like animate legion, with the following adjustments:

The area is “within close range of the caster” rather than a 15-foot radius, so massively larger.

There is no limit on the number of corpses animated.

You gain control over at least some of them (up to your animate dead limit, which plague of undead shares).

The material component is 100 gp worth of black sapphire, rather than a single 100-gp black onyx. It still does not scale with the number of corpses targeted.


Plague of undead has a line saying

The bones and bodies required for this spell follow the same restrictions as animate dead.

so plague of undead raises the same questions about “true anatomy” and how that works with a swarm creature as animate dead and animate legion do.

...and this is how a black onyx worth 100g began the story of a terrifying plague! :)

Assuming that Bees do indeed qualify for becoming zombies at all, as answered by Nobody the Hobgoblin, I would suggest the Metamagic Feat Fell Animate from Libris Mortis: The Book of the Dead.
Fell Animate allows you to raise one or more creatures, no more Hit Dice of undead than twice your caster level, as zombies if they are slain by a spell modified by this feat.
Slay a swarm with a Fell Animate modified spell that does Are of Effect damage, such as Burning Hands and you should have a swarm of Zombees.
Note that this feat doesn't necessitate the individual handling of the target corpses, like Animate Dead does, and it doesn't require expensive Material Components (other than what the base spell to be modified costs to cast).

Is there a spell level mod to this feat?

Found it. It's a +3 spell level mod on top of the AOE you're using to blast the swarm. Still effective, but the "slain outright" part can get costly to build up to.

Fell Animate is a great thought! But this answer should note that the feat includes “Any living creature that could normally be raised as a zombie,” and “The standard rules for controlling undead (see animate dead, page 198 of the Player’s Handbook) apply to newly created undead gained through this metamagic feat,” since those rules may or may not invoke the “true anatomy” rule that is so questionable with swarms.

While I think this answer is a thorough examination of using Animate Dead, this situation looks to me like one that might be better suited to using an original spell. I don't know that the rules for original spells are laid out in the srd20, but page 198 in the DMG contains information on doing so. Perhaps you could research an Animate Dead Swarm spell that would allow you to have a straightforward solution that is tailor-made to your needs and cleanly resolves any issues. You would need to compare the power level of what you are trying to accomplish to determine the target spell level and then pay a decent chunk of gold up-front to discover if your spell was actually possible (i.e. allowed by the DM), but otherwise you could ensure that you can know exactly the rules for how this situation would be treated.

Animate Dead Is Possible but Wasteful.
Let's start with the root information.

Animate Dead (PHB1 v3.5 pg199)

Range: Touch
This spell turns the bones or bodies of dead creatures into undead skeletons or zombies
They remain animated until they are destroyed (and cannot be animated again)
You can't create more HD than twice caster level
You can't control more than 4x caster level HD at once
Skeleton: The corpse must have bones
Zombie: The corpse must have a true anatomy "So a dead gelatinous cube, for example, cannot be animated as a zombie."
Material component: Onyx gem worth at least 25gp per HD of undead in mouth or eye socket of each corpse you intend to animate




Vermin Type (MM1 v3.5 pg317)
This type includes insects, arachnids, other artropohs, worms and similar vertibrates
8-sided Hit Die



Swarm Subtype (MM1 v3.5 pg315)
A swarm is a collection of fine, diminutive, or tiny creatures that acts as one creature. A swarm has no discernable anatomy



You cannot animate a swarm (Anatomy)
You can animate individual insects by creature type (but must be touching them at cast)
You cannot make an insect a skeleton, anatomically (covering bases)
You can make an insect a zombie, anatomically
The spell requires a mostly intact corpse, which may be difficult to do as creatures more than two size categories larger are likely the reason they died
The material components would be almost impossible to apply unless an onyx the size of a grain of sand was used or the bee(s) in question were enlarged significantly at time of casting. An individual creature can never have less than 1HD.

So while it's possible to raise a bee as a zombie with Animate Dead as written, it's a lot of effort to get maybe two dozen bees when you could be creating much more dangerous things.

The question is about D&D 3.5, while your citations are about 5e. This makes your answer irrelevant to the question.

@ValhallaGH : My apologies. Adjusting my answer for rule set.

@ValhallaGH: Changed my answer for the edition.

−1, many issues. “we need to get into how many bees you can physically touch at once,” maybe, maybe not, and anyway, we know this, it’s 6. “A swarm is up to 1,000 flying insects per medium sized creature cloud,” at bees’ size, it’s 10,000 per swarm—which has a Large space. “They would qualify as having ‘true anatomy’ given that they have discernable body parts, muscles, and organs,” assumes a very precise definition of “true anatomy” not given anywhere in the rules. “Bees are ‘small or smaller objects,’” highly ambiguous (top two answers disagree).

@KRyan: Starting small. 10 would be the lowest maximum for a level 5 wizard. But not the absolute max. I used "tiny" because it's the smallest sized stat block in the Animated Object lists. The spell doesn't distinguish between "fine" and "tiny" in the casting. We've established on other questions that dead bodies are considered objects. I will fix the swarm size to reflect "Large". There really isn't a way that a bee's anatomy isn't as discernable as a human's. The main structural difference is exoskeleton (which would discount skeletons but the question didn't want those)

We have not established in other questions that dead bodies are considered objects—I linked to the canonical question on that subject and pointed out how the top two—each highly-rated—answers disagree on exactly that point. Calling it “established” is simply incorrect. And the question isn’t whether “a bee” has a “true anatomy,” the question is whether a swarm does—does the fact that this singular creature is composed of 10,000 bodies mean that the creature does not have any one “true anatomy”? I don’t know, but I do know that you don’t know.

@KRyan : A swarm is a group of potentially thousands of creatures grouped together for DM sanity. Animate Dead says "one or more corpses touched". Hence you would have to touch every bee you'd want to bring back. A given bee has anatomy. It would be like arguing that you could resurrect a squad of humans by touching one because they moved in formation to resurrect a whole swarm. The "established bodies are objects" I meant another question thread asking exactly that. I accidentally removed the link. It has been re-added.

It’s not remotely like that, and that kind of strawman proves that this debate is fruitless. I have downvoted because I think this answer is poor and unhelpful, and I have explained in detail why. What you do with that is up to you.

@KRyan: It's not a strawman argument. It's comparable. It's several individual beings acting as a group. If you were acting at the scale of an ancient dragon, an army of humans would be the same. It is an army if individual insects. If we were talking about the Anansi in WoD then it would be another story.

Swarms are singular creatures by the rules; groups of humans or dragons are not. Hence, completely incomparable, and strawman. Also, your link “proving” that corpses are objects is from 5e—again.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Let us not. I have downvoted this answer; if you fix the issues I’ve raised here, I may change my vote. I am not otherwise going to engage with this any more.

@KRyan: I was using the suggested action of "avoiding extended discussions in comments". I didn't choose the wording of the link. That said, I removed the Animate Objects section since the PHB definition (rather than online sources I found) of the spell lists "materials such as".  I restructured my statements on Animate Dead and stand by my initial assertion - not as a swarm, and it's quite an involved process for little payout.

Your assertion remains only that: an un-backed-up assertion that ignores the very real possibility that the text may be interpreted in other ways. Calling this “root information” is simply inaccurate; it is one possibility among a few different ones. You have not, and cannot, back up your assertion that it is the only possible meaning, because it is not.

@KRyan: It's the root information because it comes directly from the core rulebooks. I didn't say it's "the only possible meaning", either. You also didn't haven't said what's wrong with my sourcing or interpretation of that source, just sort of dragged me. An individual animal has anatomy - including the eyes and/or mouth the spell requires.
